# GCJ 2020 qualification round: Parenting Partnering Returns. What could be possibly wrong with my approach?

Tags: python-3.x, greedy

I am aware of the activities selection problem that can be seen [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/activity-selection-problem-greedy-algo-1/). Since we need to find for 2 people, i tried finding max possible jobs for Cameron and then removed all the jobs that can be done by Cameron. Then, in the remaining activities, I found the max possible jobs that can be done by Jamie. If there are still jobs left to be done, I say its impossible, else i print the person in order of the jobs.

The code works fine for the sample cases and I have myself tried several other cases but was unable to find a corner case that gave wrong answer. And still, GCJ says it is not giving the right answers.

Any fault in approach, ideas, corner cases or a different method altogether is appreciated.

question can be found [here](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/000000000019fd27/000000000020bdf9)
and my code is

```py
cases = int(input())
for tt in range(cases):
    n = int(input())
    pl1 = []
    pl2 = []
    activ = []
    cjc = []
    cjj = []
    plx2 = []
    plx1 = []

    for xx in range(n):
        p1,p2 = list(map(int,input().split()))
        pl1.append(p1)
        pl2.append(p2)
        activ.append([p1,p2])
    pl = sorted(pl2)
    p02 = pl[0]
    p01 = pl1[pl2.index(p02)]
    cjj.append([p01,p02])
    activ.remove([p01,p02])

    for p2 in pl[1:]:
        p1 = pl1[pl2.index(p2)]
        if(p1>=p02):
            cjj.append([p1,p2])
            activ.remove([p1,p2])
            p02=p2

    if(len(activ)>0):
        for i in activ:
            plx1.append(i[0])
            plx2.append(i[1])
        pll = sorted(plx2)
        p02 = pll[0]
        p01 = plx1[plx2.index(p02)]
        cjc.append([p01,p02])
        activ.remove([p01,p02])
        for p2 in pll[1:]:
            p1 = plx1[plx2.index(p2)]
            if(p1>=p02):
                cjc.append([p1,p2])
                activ.remove([p1,p2])
                p02=p2


    s = ''
    fff = False
    if(len(activ)>0):
        s = "IMPOSSIBLE"
    else:
        s = ''
        for i in range(n):
            if(fff == False):
                p1 = pl1[i]
                p2 = pl2[i]
                if([p1,p2] in cjc):
                    s+='C'
                elif([p1,p2] in cjj):
                    s+='J'
                else:
                    s = "IMPOSSIBLE"
                    fff = True

    ss = "Case #"+str(tt+1)+":"
    print(ss,s)
```

Comment: Please [edit] question with readable code (i.e. `ffff` is unreadable variable name), complete problem statement in the question and necessary test cases that show failures. In current state it is hard to know what (if anything) wrong with your code. When editing post make sure you have rights to provide the content in the post that meets SO license (cc by-sa 4.0 with attribution required)

Comment: You fail on the input (a solution is JCCCJ):
5
380 493
574 661
205 566
702 1148
512 729
Found here: https://repl.it/@mrtea/GCJ3, which suggest there is some issue with sorting in your code.